# phplist: Will imported users receive a confirmation mail?

Tags: newsletter, phplist

I have to set up a new phplist installation and need to import ~20.000 email accounts from another source to a list.

When I'll import these users, will there be an email to each of them with a request for confirmation? Earlier versions of phplist had a setting for this but it seems to be missing from newer versions and I could not find anything in the docs.

The problem is that all of the addresses have already been confirmed elsewhere and users might be irritated by receiving a new confirmation mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently imported about 2,000 subscribers and no request for confirmation emails were sent. My version is v3.0.12